# reset form and change the submit button text

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an form and I'm processing it using ajax. I want the form to be submitted and the button text to change if the form is submitted successfully. The problem is that if I reset the form the text doesn't change. If I don't reset the form then the text changes but you cannot submit the form again. I would like for the user to be able to toggle between two choices. For example, they can turn something on or off - if on - the button reads - "Turn Off" and if off - the button reads - "Turn On" here's my code:

```
$( 'form' ).each( function( i, el ) {
        var $el = $( this );

        if ( $el.hasClass( 'form-ajax-discount-button' ) ) {
            $el.on( 'submit', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $submit = $el.find( 'button' ),
                    action = $el.attr( 'action' );

                // button loading
                $submit.button( 'loading' );

                $.ajax({
                    type     : 'POST',
                    url      : action,
                    data     : $el.serialize() + '&ajax=1',
                    dataType : 'JSON',
                    success  : function( response ) {

                        // custom callback
                        $el.trigger( 'form-ajax-response', response );
                        // reset button
                        $submit.button( 'reset' );
                        // success
                        $submit.html( response.message );   
                    },
                })
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this code that toggles text when being clicked, is that what you're looking for?

```
$(function(){
   $(".pushme").click(function () {
      $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "PUSH ME" ? "DON'T PUSH ME" : "PUSH ME";
      })
   });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CBajb/